# Всех приветствую. Можете помочь товарищи!

Tags: kotlin, авторизация, регистрация

Прохожу курсы, у одного человека. Сидел сутки на задачей, выполнил ее с трудом. А теперь оказывается не правильно. Может кто совет даст, буду благодарен.
Прикрепляю два скрина. Там указаны ошибки, которые нужно исправить.
Собственно сам код.

```
//   Регистрация пользователя
println("Пожалуйста зарегистрируйтесь:")
Thread.sleep(1000)`
println("Введите логин")
val userName = readln()
println("Введите пороль")
val password = readln()
Thread.sleep(1000)
println("Вы зарегистрированы!")

//Вход в приложение
do {
    println("Введите логин")
    val login = readln()
    println("Введите пороль")
    val passwordNew = readln()
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    if (userName == login && password == passwordNew) {

        //Капча
        println("Докажите что вы не БОТ\nСложите 2 числа:")
        for (i in 3 downTo 0) {
            val number = (1..9).random()
            val numberTwo = (1..9).random()
            println("${number}+${numberTwo}=")
            val unswer = readln().toInt()
            when (unswer) {
                number + numberTwo -> {
                    println("Добро пожаловать! ")
                    break
                }
                else -> println("Осталось $i попытка")
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                println("Доступ запрещен")
                break
            }
        }
    } else println("Не верный логин или пороль")
} while (userName != login || password != passwordNew)
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) логин пароль сравнивается в 2х местах. Лучше пусть в одном 2) зачем when (unswer), чем не угодил банальный if 3) будет написано ""Осталось 0 попытка" и сразу "Доступ запрещен"

Comment: Можно на примере? Я не знаю как задать "unswer" в if. Так же нужно чтобы, при положительном решении капчи, выводилось "добро пожаловать"

Answer (score -1):

У каждого свое мнение какой должен быть рефакторинг, все таки это тестовое задание и многое можно упустить (ту же проверку при регистрации, что не ввели пустой логин или пароль. И то, что в любом результате выполнение выходит в одну точку), поэтому по своим замечаниям.

1. логин пароль сравнивается в 2х местах.

Лучше пусть в одном
двойное сравнение можно заменить одним `while(true) + break`, `do..while(флаг выхода из цикла)`. С флагом проще в языках где нет `break N`, но в котлине есть `break@label`, а значит можно и `loop@ while (true)...break@loop`

2. зачем when (unswer), чем не угодил банальный if
3. будет написано ""Осталось 0 попытка" и сразу "Доступ запрещен"

when имеет смысл как замена многочисленных if. Но у вас же нет множества условий и вы усложнили простое.

```
if (answer == number + numberTwo) {
    println("Добро пожаловать! ")
    break
} else {
    if (i > 0) {
        println("Осталось $i попытка")
    } else {
        println("Доступ запрещен")
        break
    }
}
```

Ну и полный код (убрал Thread.sleep(1000))

```
//   Регистрация пользователя
println("Пожалуйста зарегистрируйтесь:")
println("Введите логин")
val userName = readln()
println("Введите пароль")
val password = readln()
println("Вы зарегистрированы!")

//Вход в приложение
loop@ while (true) {
    println("Введите логин")
    val login = readln()
    println("Введите пароль")
    val passwordNew = readln()

    if (userName == login && password == passwordNew) {
        //Капча
        println("Докажите что вы не БОТ\nСложите 2 числа:")
        for (i in 3 downTo 0) {
            val number = (1..9).random()
            val numberTwo = (1..9).random()
            println("${number}+${numberTwo}=")
            val answer = readln().toInt()

            if (answer == number + numberTwo) {
                println("Добро пожаловать! ")
                break@loop
            } else {
                if (i > 0) {
                    println("Осталось $i попытка")
                } else {
                    println("Доступ запрещен")
                    break@loop
                }
            }
        }
    } else println("Неверный логин или пароль")
}
```